# String literal type parameter not enforced

Tags: typescript

With Redux (this question has nothing to do with Redux in particular though) I want to have the name of the action that a reducer uses, but I want to make sure that the name and the action used in the reducer correspond. So I wrote this code:

```
interface TypedAction<N> {
  type: N;
}

type TypedReducer<S, A extends TypedAction<any>> = (state: S, action: A) => S;

function addReducer<S, R extends TypedReducer<S, A>, A extends TypedAction<N>, N>(initialState: S, actionName: N, reducer: R): {} {
  // doesn't really matter what is returned here
  // the point is I need the actionName during run time
  // but want it to correspond with the reducer's action's name at compile time
  return {
    [actionName.toString()]: reducer
  };
}
```

However when I try an example:

```
interface MyAction extends TypedAction<'MyAction'> {
  foo: string;
}

const myActionReducer: TypedReducer<number, MyAction> = (state: number, action: MyAction) => state+1;

addReducer(1, "foo", myActionReducer); // should give a compile error, because "foo" and is not of type "MyAction"
```

Why does Typescript not enforce that `"foo"` should be `"MyAction"`?

Comment: When  all `addReducer` arguments are considered together, it's possible to satisfy all constraints with N inferred as union type `"foo" | "MyAction"`. Why does TypeScript widen a type of  `"foo"` to  `"foo" | "MyAction"`? Probably because it allows some other real-life code to compile that some people thought ought to be compiled without errors. Is there any way to add a constraint telling that `N` should be a (singular) string literal type - I don' t know.

Comment: My colleague figured it out actually. He will post the answer. If you place `extends string` behind the definition of N in the `TypedAction` and the `addReducer` TypeScript all of a sudden works as expected. I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface TypedAction<T extends string> {
  type: T;
}

type TypedReducer<S, A extends TypedAction<any>> = (state: S, action: A) => S;

interface MyAction extends TypedAction<"MyAction"> {
  foo: number;
}

type ActionTypeAndReducer<S, A extends TypedAction<any>> = {
  [type: string]: TypedReducer<S, A>
};

function pair<ActionType extends string,
              A extends TypedAction<ActionType>,
              S>(type: ActionType, reducer: TypedReducer<S, A>): ActionTypeAndReducer<S, A> {
  return {
    [type as string]: reducer
  };
}

const myReducer: TypedReducer<any, MyAction> = (state: any, action: MyAction) => {};
pair("MyAction2", myReducer);
```

this will produce the expected behavior.

```
error TS2345: 
   Argument of type 'TypedReducer<any, MyAction>' is not assignable to parameter
   of type 'TypedReducer<any, TypedAction<"MyAction2">>'.

   Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.                                                                                                                           
   Type 'TypedAction<"MyAction2">' is not assignable to type 'MyAction'.                                                                                                             
   Property 'foo' is missing in type 'TypedAction<"MyAction2">'.
```

I thought that a function that combines both action and reducer could check this so I've built the pair function. **The types were ok but the compiler was complaining saying that the `type argument` had to be a `string` or a `number` because it was a key in the returned object.** So I made ActionType extend string and then the rest was fine.